# ant junit reference not found

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to compile junit java files using ant, but I am getting,

```
package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import static org.junit.Assert.*;
...
```

And, this is my part of build.xml,

```
<javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="test"/>
        <classpath refid="MyProgram.classpath"/>
    </javac>

  <path id="MyProgram.classpath">
   ...
   <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar"/>
   ...
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `junit.jar` is really located in `lib` directory?

Comment: Yes, the jar file is under lib folder.

Comment: Is it possible that your junit.jar is junit3?  The `org.junit.Assert` package is junit4, and I see junit3 has it as `junit.framework.Assert` package.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your excerpt above, that the `<path>` element appears to be inside of same target as the `<javac>` element.  Is it possible that the `<path>` element is misplaced?  (It needs to be placed before javac in the same target or outside of the target element.)

Comment: I copied wrong, the path is above the javac in the original build.xml.  thanks.

Comment: @Tony: see my other comment above - maybe junit.jar is the wrong version.  Open it up, and make sure it contains org.junit.Assert.class in the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of location in pathelement use path like this :

```
<path id="MyProgram.classpath">
     ...
    <pathelement path="lib/junit.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: Actually, I tested his build.xml as excerpted above, and the `location` attribute works fine. So I don't think it has anything to do with that.